# How to Print List from ServletListener JSTL

Tags: java, servlets, jstl, servlet-listeners

I try to print my list created in servlet listener in jstl page . When i look in page source all items to print are there but in page i do not see anything. Please tell me how fix it.

Code form servlet listener:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        List lista;
        lista = new LinkedList();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    String table_name = "weterynarz";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + Info.database_name, "root", "root");
        statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table_name);

        while (result.next()) {
            lista.add(result.getString("imie"));
            lista.add(result.getString("nazwisko"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("listaLisner", lista);
}
```

and jstl page

```
<c:forEach var="element" items="${listaLisner}" >
    <c:out value="${element}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: are you sure lista is not empty?

Comment: absolutely, but already i find cause. I forget about `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`